# How to get Elapsed Time From CountDowTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

My count down timer starts at `1:00:00`.  I want to add a result after a specific amount of time has elapsed.

Eg.:

> Time elapsed: 00:59:00
>
> Result wanted: 00:01:00

```
new CountDownTimer(get_no_of_hours, 1000) {
    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "DefaultLocale"})
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            timer_value.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
            timer_value.setText(hms);
            remaining_time = millisUntilFinished;
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onFinish() {
        long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
        Log.d("EXAM TEST", "" + end_time);
        timer_value.setText("Time Over !");
        if(timer_data.equals("finish")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ExamTestActivity2.this, ResultsPageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("in_session", true);
            intent.putExtra("time_taken_to_answer", timetaken);
            intent.putExtra("session_course_id", program_name_id);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract the `millisUntilFinished` from `get_no_of_hours`

```
long elapsedTime = get_no_of_hours - millisUntilFinished;
```

and then use the elapsedTime as you like.